# Wanted some idea to manage pending_approval and in_progress webpages in Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have written a CMS in Ruby on Rails 4 and I have managed the
webpages from the admin part.

**Webpages** **->** Anyone can create a webpage from admin after login and
each page has four status "**in_progress**", "**pending_approval**",
"**published**" and "**archived**", For now I have implemented the functionality
for one status i.e "**published**" if any webpage that has status
"published" then it will be show to the user otherwise it will through
404 error.

Now I have to implement the rest of the status for the webpages created by admin user, As per my requirement

**pending_approval , in_progress** -> I have to randomize the url and save the page inside any tmp directory and it will be visible to review team and once it's status will change to "**publish**" then move to its main folder (view/pages/file_path).

Comment: Stop using `>` to mark up your entire questions, please. It's for marking up *block quotes*, not coloring every single one of your questions entirely yellow.

Comment: @meagar thanks for your suggestion I will take care in future

Comment: It sounds like you're doing this wrong. You shouldn't be *moving files* around, especially inside of your `views` folder. Your data should sit in the database, and your files on disk should not be changing, outside of the `tmp` folder, and you shouldn't be leaving important user data in `tmp` as that folder could be cleaned at any time.